# Position of an element in a list

Tags: list, position, ocaml, element

What is the fastest way to get the position of an element in a list of element in OCaml?
I know how to get the "nth" position of an element in a list but I would like to know how to get the position of this element if I already know the value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the fastest is way is the most usual way:

1. Scan the list
2. Return the position if you hit the desired element
3. If never hit, then it is the worst case and entire list is scanned.

The time complexity will be **O(N)**

```
let index_of e l = 
  let rec index_rec i = function
    | [] -> raise Not_found
    | hd::tl -> if hd = e then i else index_rec (i+1) tl
  in
  index_rec 0 l
```

Comment: Actually you don't scan the entire list, you stop as soon as you reach the element you are looking for

Comment: @Thomash I said that return if you find the element. I wrote `entire list` just to reflect the worst case and also to reflect the fact of O(N), but I will edit in case of misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

```
let rec findi_rec base p l = match l with [] -> raise Not_found | h::_ when p h -> base | _::t -> findi_rec (base+1) p t;;

let findi p l = findi_rec 0 p l;;
```

As:

```
# findi (fun x -> x=4) [1;9;3;2;1;4;5;7];;
- : int = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If the elements in a list are all unique, you may wish to convert to a map, where the elements are keys and the indices are values. The creation of the map is O(n), but subsequently, lookups of indices are *O(log n)*.

E.g.

```
module IntMap = Map.Make (Int)

let lst = [34; 56; 17; 2; 0; 99]
let indexed_lst = List.mapi (fun x i -> (i, x)) lst
let map = List.fold_left (fun m (k, v) -> IntMap.add k v m) IntMap.empty indexed_lst
let idx_of_2 = IntMap.find 2 map
```

Now `idx_of_2` is `3`.

This is more expensive than a linear search for very low numbers of lookups, but increasingly less expensive as the number of lookups increases.